# Ubuntu won't boot after I installed a Wacom tablet driver

Tags: boot, drivers, reboot, wacom

**My computer specs**: Lenovo ThinkPad X250; dual-boot with Windows and Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-72-generic x86_64)

**What Happened**: I recently obtained a Wacom Intuos tablet for work. I plugged it into a USB port and it started working immediately, with no other steps. However, I thought I should install [a driver](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to be safe. I first installed [this kernel driver](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom) and then [this X driver](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Xf86-input-wacom).

When I restarted my computer, GNU GRUB booted normally, but when Ubuntu started, I got the following error:

```
Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
```

This error is followed by a black screen with a white underscore. Other times when I reboot, instead of the error, I just get a blank purple screen. However, I can still start up recovery mode no problem, so I've been working through that to try to fix this.

**What I've Tried**: First, I tried uninstalling the X driver with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-wacom
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-wacom
```

Then I looked at the dmesg log (*/var/log/dmesg*), and didn't really find anything useful.

Then I tried [blacklisting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_modules#Blacklisting) the kernel modules. I did this by navigating to */etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf* and adding the following lines:

```
blacklist wacom
blacklist wacom_w8001
```

I skipped the *mkinitpcio* commands because they do not exist on Ubuntu. I rebooted and this did not solve the problem.

I suspect that I have not successfully uninstalled and/or blacklisted these drivers. Any tips? If I could just get rid of these two drivers I installed and if I am able to boot my Ubuntu that would be perfect.